# handle CREATE LOGIN x WITH PASSWORD in database projects

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac

How to manage logins with password in database project in visual studio? Again I compare the database schemas and the same problem occurs - either the passwords are copied to the code repository from the dacpac files or schema compare reports differences on these logins when someone in the repo removes these passwords.

Comment: We had to add a special file for logins to handle them in DB Projects - or put them in Post Deploy scripts (which tended to work a bit better). Overall, though, I'd try to leave them out of the project. I have a small snippet of doing that per environment at https://schottsql.com/all-ssdt-articles but it was a lot of work to set it up.